# same space between element starting at the beginning and finishing at the end of the screen

Tags: android

I have a question concerning space between elements in android studio. For now I have this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/results"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/results" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/notification" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/disconnection"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/disconnect" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This gives me this result:

[image]

As you can see there are 5 images on this toolbar. I want this 5 images to be at the same distance and I want the first image to be at the extreme left of the screen and the last image to be at the extreme right.

Do you have an idea how to do it?